# Using elasticsearch-river-mysql to stream data from MySQL database to Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I want to use [elasticsearch-river-mysql](https://github.com/scharron/elasticsearch-river-mysql) in order to continuously transfer data from MySQL database to ElasticSearch. I'm beginner with ES and rivers so I hope you can help me out with my questions.

1. From what I know, the data will be streamed from the MySQL database to the ES cluster which will index it automatically. Is that correct? Are there any timeouts or limits I have to be aware of?
2. How the foreign key relations between the relational database tables will be translated into ES? Will the table row containing the foreign key become an inner object for an ES document or some other relation between the ES documents will be used?
3. Are there any disadvantages in using this river for the mentioned above purpose?
4. What will be the load on ES by implementing this? I assume that ES is powerful enough, but still I was wondering. Will the searches made on the ES cluster be affected anyhow in this scenario?

Comment: How many entries do you have in your MySQL database?

Comment: My advice already is to try to use the [elasticsearch-jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) for many reasons. One of them is that the elasticsearch-jbdc-river is more generic in case you decide to switch RDBMS and another is that the jbdc-river is still maintained when the other one hasn't been since 2 years, and Elasticsearch evolved a lot ever since

Comment: Here are some statistics about our database: total number of entries is 919161598, total number of tables is 314, total size 258,5GB, the biggest table contains 121942658 entries and is of size 25GB. So one really huge database. We have a lot of pick sales addind continuously new data to the database (not conting the new added features to the system). The growth of the database is ~10GB per month. You can see why we start to experience some performance issues when executing heavy and complex queries (especially the one done for reporting).

Comment: @eliasah thanks for the advice. Does the elasticsearch-jdbc-river support MySQL replication stream?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean by MySQL replication stream.

Comment: Have you thought about scaling out or using hadoop to process your data?

Comment: About hadoop - no, about scaling out - yes. What we want to do is actually separate our system into several small systems. So we want to do this with the database too. Every system will have a small and manageable database. But this separation will take two-three years.

Comment: If you put the amount of data on your ES cluster you have to be carefully about how you use Sharding and Replicas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My advice already is to try to use the [elasticsearch-jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) for many reasons.

One of them is that the `elasticsearch-jbdc-river` is more generic in case you decide to switch **RDBMS**.

Another is that the `jbdc-river` is still maintained when the other one hasn't been since 2 years, and Elasticsearch evolved a lot ever since.

**1. From what I know, the data will be streamed from the MySQL database to the ES cluster which will index it automatically. Is that correct? Are there any timeouts or limits I have to be aware of?**

The data from MySQL should be streamed automatically from MySQL to the Elasticsearch cluster without a timeout limitation but the bottleneck will be your JVM Heap Size. I'm not sure how much do you need to process the amount of data you have. You need to test it.

**2. How the foreign key relations between the relational database tables will be translated into ES? Will the table row containing the foreign key become an inner object for an ES document or some other relation between the ES documents will be used?**

Elasticsearch is schemaless so you need to [manage to the inside Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch). The river just streams the data into your cluster. You can define your mapping when you create your index and then use the river to stream it into the ES cluster.

**3. Are there any disadvantages in using this river for the mentioned above purpose?**

The river will be replaced with another cleaner way to stream these data but this is the best solution you have for now.

Comment: Which alternatives/cleaner ways are there in development? Seems like this river is still actively maintained and here to stay, right?

Comment: I think about Logstash maybe. I'm not sure. I haven't tried that approach yet. But I think that you might be able to use Logstash to forward data flow from your database toward a elasticsearch cluster